# MariaDB enable TLS but still allow connections without TLS

Tags: ssl, mariadb

I have one MariaDB "M". On the same machine sits an application "A", which accesses it. On a different server is another application "B" accessing it, too.

Now I want to enable TLS on MariaDB to secure the connection B -> M.

Due to $reasons I cannot change the config of app A.

Question now is: Will the plain connection (without TLS) from A -> M still work after activating TLS on the DB?

Comment: The docs say that you can do this: [Requiring TLS for Specific User Accounts](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/securing-connections-for-client-and-server/#requiring-tls-for-specific-user-accounts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, unencrypted connections will still work, unless you specifically enforce the usage of an encrypted connection.

This can be done globally by setting the require_secure_transport system variable, or on a per-user basis:

```
ALTER USER 'user'@'%' REQUIRE SSL;
```